# "Imagine the world" or "imagine a world"?

Tags: articles

I came across a sentence while watching a YouTube video which was:

> Imagine the world powered by mushrooms.

Shouldn't there be "a" instead of "the"?

Comment: "Imagine the world..." means "Imagine this world (the one we know)..." while "Imagine a world..." points to a fantasy, a non-existing world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imagine **the** world powered by mushrooms.

Mean imagine the same world into which one you are living, but powered by mushrooms.

> Imagine **a** world powered by mushrooms.

Mean imagine a unreal world powered by mushrooms. The **"a"** here accentuates the idea of an imaginary world or an unrealizable idea.